# Ggplot2 : do not display 0 value in pie chart labels

Tags: r, pie-chart

I'm trying to make a pie chart without displaying the 0 value label and I'm unable to do it.

My data :

```
group <- factor(c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"))
prod <-factor(c("Fong","Fong","Fong","Herb","Herb","Herb","Ins","Ins","Ins","Other","Other","Other"))
quant <- c(0,1,0,2,1,1,0,5,3,8,4,6)

df <- data.frame(group, prod, quant)
```

My script :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=quant, fill=prod))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0)+
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  geom_text(aes(label=quant), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

Here, this is the result :
[Pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BijMU.png)

Is there any solution to not display the 0 value labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your `0` values with NAs, for example with, `dplyr::na_if(0)` on your dataframe:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::na_if(0) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x="", y=quant, fill=prod))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0)+
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  geom_text(aes(label=quant), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```